# how to create iso image from DVD

Tags: iso, dvd

I want to create an iso image from my bootable DVD. I want to create direct DVD to iso image.
Please suggest me the right way to create iso image from DVD.

Answer (score 66):

Insert the CD or DVD that you want to make an ISO image of, and open a terminal window.  To do that, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo cat /dev/srx > /home/<user_name>/<file_name.iso>
```

Make sure that you replace **(x)** with your device number.

for example in my case I would do:

```
sudo cat /dev/sr0 > /home/mitch/example.iso
```

Comment: Mitch's comment using the terminal is also good in the case of trying to copy a home-made DVD which has invalid characters in the file name or title. I recently couldn't get Brasero to make an ISO of a DVD with slashes in the name (the DIY idiot used slashes to date the title - probably worked in Windows!). But at the terminal I could specify a new name and it all worked ok.

Comment: Great now how do I find out what is my device number?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne use `sudo lshw -class disk` to find your device(s) number.

Comment: I guess thats simplest method! And it does work both ways, dvd to iso and iso to dvd, thanks a lot !

Comment: This is amazingly awesome!

Comment: This method fails and gives me `cat: /dev/sr0: Input/output error` when trying to make an iso-file out of an audio cd (a cd with wav tracks on it).

Comment: For audio discs, I found [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1391249&p=11647390#post11647390) useful :)

Comment: `/dev/dvdrw` also works. On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, it's a symlink to `/dev/sr0`

Comment: If you have a windows cd then use the command `sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom of=filename.iso` to convert it automatically to iso

Comment: I wanted to do a CD, so in ubuntu on my device `sudo cat /dev/cdrom > filename.iso`.

Comment: This option takes FOREVER though!

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I get "cat: /dev/sr0: Input/output error"

Answer (score 27):

Either use Brasero, like Mohammad Etemaddar suggested, or dd, as described here: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-ISO-File-in-Linux

The method which is described in WikiHow: `dd if=/dev/cdrom of=~/cdrom_image.iso`

if: input file

of: output file

dd: disk dump

Another very good description on making ISO image has been written [here](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/08/01/make-iso-images-on-linux/).

Comment: I'd rather use a designated tool like `dd` than piping all data as suggested in accepted answer. +1!
For dd you can append `status=progress` for feedback about … well…  progress :)

Answer (score 24):

In `Brasero Disk Burner` which is installed on Ubuntu by default, select `Disc Copy` and select `Disk image` for `Select a Disk to write to` and create image.

Comment: that does not create .IMG or .ISO files

Comment: @RonanDejhero Please accept my apologize, I have not Ubuntu installed on my laptop. But this may help you:
http://kvz.io/blog/2007/08/01/make-iso-images-on-linux/

Comment: It does create an ISO running Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

i know that imgburn (for windows) works flawlessly on the lastest wine, tried it myself while navigating my windows partition