# How to share a CD-ROM drive over the network in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, permissions, dvd, drive, cd

I have 3 Computers and only one of them is old enough to have a CD/DVD-ROM drive. I would like to access the media from the other computers as well.

I have mounted it under `/media` in the computer where the drive is attached and then tried to access it via sshfs from the other computers by connecting it with Nautilus. I get the error message "You don't have the permissions necessary to view the content of "media"". If I connect to the host computer via ssh and issue the command

`sudo ls -la /media` (without `sudo`it doesn't work)

the result is

```
total 8
d--x--x---  3 andrea andrea   88 Jul 22  2007 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root   root   4096 Jul 20 10:32 ..
dr-xr-xr-x  2 andrea andrea  508 Jul 22  2007 VIDEO_TS
```

and if I try to `sudo chmod 777 .` it tells me "chmod: changing permissions of '.': read only file system" and nothing is changed.

Is there a way to share a CD or DVD drive over the network?

Comment: Have you tried with [samba](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=829658) ?

Comment: You can [create an iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307688/how-to-create-iso-image-from-dvd), and then [mount the iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164227/how-to-mount-an-iso-file)